# PCI Compliance and Git

Tags: pci-dss, git

We are currently moving to get a ci\cd pipeline running on Gitlab.
Our current set up is we have a non-production and a production environment on separate networks. This reduces the PCI scope to just the Production network as this is the only place cardholder data is present.

We get a deployment to production by the following:

1. Commit code to git
2. This kicks off current build of artefacts via cruise control
3. In non-production we deploy this via scripts, which have access to artefacts
4. For production we make the artefacts available to production by
   pushing to SFTP server and run scripts on production jump server to
   deploy

We are now working to moving to use Gitlab where:

1. Gitlab running in non-prod environment
2. Gitlab registry running in non-prod environment with docker images stored in file system for now, eventually to something like s3
3. GitLab runner running in non-prod environment

Our issue is for the cd part we need to push images to production boxes and run docker commands (docker run). This results in our non-production environment (via runner running pipeline) to have access to production which we never required.

Any guidance on how to avoid this and keep our production environment as restricted as possible? I presume lots of companies want to keep production restricted and how do they achieve this?